# TCP Connection freezes while waiting for answer

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I recently startet .NET programming and tried to do a small network game.
The Connection is set up properly and messages get mostly written and read at normal behaviour. But at some random point on runtime, the reading stream doesn't recognize the incoming message.

The Connection is set up via Tcp listener and the corresponding stream.

```
//Get the network Stream
stream = client.GetStream();
w = new BinaryWriter(stream);
r = new BinaryReader(stream);
```

As I said before, the communication is working, but seems to freeze at a random time ingame at the following point:

```
 //Waiting for enemy to attack
    public int ready()
    {
        try
        {
            while (r.ReadString() != ClientMessages.ATTACK) { }
            Thread.Sleep(20);
            return r.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("Dead");
        }
    }
```

It's always the same, that it get stuck within the while-loop. The Binary Reader doesn't seem to notice any further client messages no matter how many times I send the "Attack" order.
But the program is not somewhere in no man's land... if I shut down the connection, the method throws its "connection lost exception" just as normal.

At first I thought that I had screwed up something in this method, but in the following example, where I do almost the same, everything's perfect (or at least seems to be.. got never stuck at this point)

```
//Waiting for feedback
    public int waitforfeedback()
    {
        try
        {
            while (r.ReadString() != ClientMessages.HIT) { }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            return r.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("Dead");
        }
    }
```

Is it possible, that the problem is caused by a backgroundworker (which I use to call the network methods)?

What should I do to handle this problem?

**EDIT :**
As requested, the Backgroundworker code:

```
private void waiting()
    {
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

        setter = true;
        button.Content = "Waiting";
        this.IsEnabled = false;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

            int hit = network.ready();
            e.Result = hit;
    }
```

Comment: I wonder... have you tried pinging the client in a 'keep alive' fashion?

Comment: What part of your code is executed inside of the backgroundworker ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but the client (or server, problem is both ways) still responds if the connection is closed.. so I don't think pinging would help that much. But could try anyway